# Applying Euler's Eq to $x^2y^{\prime\prime}-3xy^\prime+4y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, second-order-logic

I was looking over the solution to this problem and they came out with $y(x) = c_1x^2 + c_2x^2\log x$. I don't know where the $\log x$ came from. I got this as my final solution: $c_1e^{1 + i(12^{1/2})/2} + c_2 c_1e^{1 - i(12^{1/2})/2}$?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx

Comment: I've done my best to convert your write-up to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but I couldn't discern whether $12^{1/2}/2$ meant $\sqrt{3}$ or something else, so feel free to amend further. Your "solution" as it stands is constant; perhaps you wanted a factor of $x$ in each exponent?

Comment: The error apparently was that the characteristic equation $0=r(r-1)-3r+4$ was transformed into $0=r^2-2r+4=(r-1)^2+3$ instead of the correct $0=r^2-4r+4=(r-2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got your own answer (perhaps you could edit it into your question), but with $t:=\ln x$ we have $\dot{y}=xy^\prime$ so$$\ddot{y}=x\left(xy^\prime\right)^\prime=x^2y^{\prime\prime}+xy^\prime=x^2y^{\prime\prime}+\dot{y}.$$Hence $$\ddot{y}-4\dot{y}+4=0\implies y=(c_1+c_2t)e^{2t}=(c_1+c_2\ln x)x^2.$$The $\ln x$ is due to a repeated root in our characteristic polynomial. if you're unfamiliar with what these yield, let me explain. Defining $D:=\frac{d}{dt},\,z:=e^{-2t}y$, we can rewrite the problem as $$0=e^{-2t}(D-2)^2(e^{2t}z)=e^{-2t}(D-2)(e^{2t}\dot{z})=e^{-2t}(e^{2t}\ddot{z})=\ddot{z},$$which of course has a linear-in-$t$ solution.

Comment: what's t := lnx mean? How does that lead to y = xy'?

Comment: @DylanY $:=$ means "is defined as". For example, $y^\prime:=\frac{dy}{dx}$, while $\dot{y}:=\frac{dy}{dt}$ introduces a similar notation for $t$-derivatives. By the chain rule, $$\dot{y}=\frac{dx}{dt}y^\prime=xy^\prime,$$since $t=\ln x\implies x=e^t\implies\frac{dx}{dt}=x$.